# Json loads function fails to convert to dictionary if nested 3 levels or deeper

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I'm taking in a json value sent in a body request to a Python / Django app like so:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/devices/1/?json={ "DeviceId":"1-9024-9929", "Date":"1/4/2019 9:52:2", "Location":"-1.000000000,-1.000000000", "Key":"{XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}", "Data":"{\"Value0\":\"{ \"ReferenceValue\":\"Elevation\", \"Prediction\":18.297534944, \"ModelPredictionFit\":3.196141712e-2, \"PCBasedEstimatedError\":3.196141712e-2, \"PCScore\":4.855016704, \"PredictionValueScore\":4.687027008e-2}\",}"}
```

When received server-side, I use json.loads to convert to

```
{'DeviceId': '1-9024-9929', 'Date': '1/4/2019 9:52:2', 'Location': '-1.000000000,-1.000000000', 'Key': '{XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}', 'Data': '{"Value0":"{ "ReferenceValue":"Elevation", "Prediction":18.297534944, "ModelPredictionFit":3.196141712e-2, "PCBasedEstimatedError":3.196141712e-2, "PCScore":4.855016704, "PredictionValueScore":4.687027008e-2}",}'}
```

While I'm able to access any values via the appropriate key, such as

```
receivedJson["DeviceId"]

> 1-9024-9929
```

the 'Data' key cannot be used to access children as it isn't properly formatted:

```
recievedJson["Data"]

> {"Value0":"{ "ReferenceValue":"Elevation", "Prediction":18.297534944, "ModelPredictionFit":3.196141712e-2, "PCBasedEstimatedError":3.196141712e-2, "PCScore":4.855016704, "PredictionValueScore":4.687027008e-2}",}
```

What is the most efficient way to convert this nested array back into a json / dictionary usable format (keys requiring single quotes)?

Comment: Do you have control over how the `json` is generated from the client side? Seems like the most efficient way is to ensure a valid `json` is sent instead of nested `json` strings.  Failing that, are *always* expecting `Data` to be the a nested `json` string and the only one that is improperly formatted? If it doesn't need to scale it's a simpler problem.  If you have varying degree of nested `json` objects that *may be* improperly formatted then it's a different story.

Comment: While i don't have control over the client-side submission, there will never be any additional levels of nesting occuring.

Answer (score 0):

`receivedJson['Data']` is probably dumped twice by mistake. You can always check for value type before parsing it. To check if the value is a dumped JSON you can first use a function like this.

```
def is_json(json_):
   try:
      json.loads(json_)
      return True
   except Exception as e:
      return False
```

Comment: This doesn't help as I can already see receivedJson["Data"] is not formatted properly - the keys are still in double quotes; they must be single quotes to be in a usable json / dict format.

Comment: @Hikalea huh? Maybe I'm not understanding the context here but JSON requires that all quotes are double quotes, so anything with single quotes is not in a usable json format by definition.